# Is it possible to avoid old style '%' string formatting for this python string

Tags: python-2.7

I'm trying to remove all traces of old style string formatting in our python (2.7) code. However I've hit an example where only the old-style seems to work.

```
>>> x = u'\xa3'
>>> y = '{}'.format(x)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa3' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

And here's the code using old style which works ok

```
>>> y = '%s' % x
```

Is there a way of making this work using some form of { } syntax?

Comment: If you used Python 3, what you have tried would work. Why are you still using Python 2? It is no longer supported.

Comment: I am migrating an old code base to python3 and I have it py2 and 3 compatible

Answer (score 1):

You can use a unicode literal instead:

```
y = u'{}'.format(x)
```

Comment: Thanks but then I force the resultant string to be unicode regardless of x

Comment: It's better to have a consistent returning data type for any given operation than not, which is also why `/` always returns a `float` in Python 3 whereas in Python 2 it could be either an `int` or a `float`.